# Should I include my email address in an ebook?

Tags: self-publishing, kindle

I am wondering if it is appropriate to include my email address on the title page of my short stories on Amazon Kindle.

If so, is it wise to use one obtained from say Yahoo because it will not change even when I change my service provider.

Comment: `javeer-baker.com` is currently free...

Comment: @MichaelKjörling: I hope you didn't check that with one of the online services dedicated to check whether a domain is free. Because in that case, you're almost guaranteed that now it is held by a domain squatter.

Comment: @celtschk I feel fairly certain that VeriSign are reputable in that regard. And I still get `No match for "JAVEER-BAKER.COM".`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm answering this as a technician, not as a writer: it's not wise to share your email anywhere in Internet, and I believe it's valid for ebooks also.

I say that because your email will become public and a lot of people - and scripts - you don't know will use it. That will make sure you will receive in your email SPAM, STRANGE MESSAGES, UNDESIRABLE CRITICISM, etc.. That's a reason for most websites not use emails anymore, preferring on line contact pages instead.

There are other - and safer - ways for people to contact you.

For example, you can create a free blog or a webpage, and people will be able to contact you from there without actually knowing your email; or a facebook page.

It makes much more sense to add a webpage address to your ebook than your email, specially because a webpage can be expanded and changed later if you want to.

Comment: +1 for the suggestion to make a web page instead. Even if you do nothing else, you can put links to places to purchase your *other* short stories there! And *do* register a nice domain name for it. A domain name and hosting is a small expense, especially in comparison to the more professional "feel" of http://www.example.com than http://www.example.net/~meauthor. It is also trivial then to move your web site between ISPs as their offerings and your needs change.

Comment: I agree with the points about spam and strange messages, but I don't agree about undesirable criticism. If you don't want to be criticised, don't publish anything. And if the criticism is undesired, you certainly would prefer it to be in private communication, rather than in a publicly accessible place.

Comment: For criticism, understand trolls that just want to make your life hell. I'm ok with good criticism.

Comment: It's worth noting that web contact forms occasionally forward spam along. That said, it's much rarer than with email. Web contact forms are the way to go.

Comment: @NeilFein Just please don't label it "**e-mail** me" on the web site :)