# Is it appropriate to list my website as the publisher of my stories?

Tags: self-publishing, websites

Following my question [here](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/8085/should-i-include-my-email-address-in-an-ebook), I am planning to establish a personal website. It will have basic personal details and synposis of my short stories. The overarching goal will be to use the website to promote my stories. i.e. the personal website will act as a marketing tool.

I am going to publish my stories through Amazon. This is a self-publishing platform and to increase the visibility/sale of my stories, I want to list my personal website as the publisher of my book. **Please note that I want to list my website as the publisher.** I know many writers simply list their websites with their stories but I want to list my personal website as the publisher.

**Question:** Is it appropriate to list my personal website as the publisher of my stories?

Comment: How to register a domain name is off-topic here, and since that's the main part of your question (it's the title, after all), I'm closing this. Your additional question, about listing your website as publisher, would be fine, though. If you'd like to edit, maybe expanding that part, we'd be happy to consider re-opening.

Comment: For how to register a domain name, you may want to try on [Webmasters.SE](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/). However, the easy answer to that is to just contact a web hosting company in your country and tell them that you want a web hosting account and a domain name associated with it. Do ask around about prices since they can vary wildly between service providers, and ask about prices before you provide any particulars (the risk of domain squatting is small, but non-zero). And *make sure* that the domain name ownership is in *your* name, not that of the web hosting provider.

Comment: @NeilFein I have update my questions. Thanks for the comments to keep it on topic.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, you're the one "publishing" your book. Your website is where a reader could go to learn more about you, but unless you have your own site (not hosted by a service like Blogger or Wordpress), I would suspect that you probably don't want to list your website as your publisher. Of course, I will defer to anyone who has more experience in this area.